# Перевод из 16 ричной системы в читабельный

Tags: c#, системы-счисления

Есть ПО для домофона, оно отправляет на локальный ip и порт инфу о тех кто может заходить, конечной точкой выступает контроллер домофона. У меня задача переписать ПО, исходов текущего ПО у меня нет. Я сделал следующий код :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPAddress iPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.105");
    int port = 8000;

    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(iPAddress, port);

    tcpListener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений... ");

        TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент. Выполнение запроса...");

        //Читаем что прислал клиент
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = 0;
        do
        {
            bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            builder.Append(parseIMEI(data, bytes));
        }
        while (stream.DataAvailable);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("logs.txt", true))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    }

}
    private static string parseIMEI(Byte[] byteBuffer, int size)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var result = Parsebytes(byteBuffer, index, size);
        return result;
    }

    private static string Parsebytes(Byte[] byteBuffer, int index, int Size)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(byteBuffer, index, Size).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
```

Этот IP и порт прописал в текущем рабочем ПО якобы это контроллер, когда хочу добавить юзера на проход в консоле вижу это 02A062FF001900000000000000FFFF000000000000000000506564726F0000006A03 при кодировке в другие тип получаю кракозяблы. Вопрос в следующем, как распрасить эти значения, что бы можно было прочитать что именно он отправляет?

Comment: Это может быть закрытый формат. На чем написано ПО? Можно попробовать декомпилировать.

Comment: @Alex78191 игрался с кодировками. Иногда проскакивает то что я писал когда сохранял доступ напримр (:(:?:*:*( myLoginTest лРАРАоJK**#&(&* . ПО называется Access control system 2011, оно для домофонов и/или систем СКУД пропусков

Comment: Вроде получается «Pedro» — это правильно?

Comment: @VladD да) А что там еще?

Comment: там часть данных двоичная, вы ее не  переведете в символы, надо догадаться что она может значить Что касается символов http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: [Так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583279/converting-byte-array-containing-ascii-characters-to-a-string) нужно конвертировать массив байт в строку. Чтобы убрать лишние символы можете обрезать строку или удалить байты.

Comment: *"исходов текущего ПО у меня нет"* -- даже частичный реверс-инжиниринг уже собранных файлов может здорово облегчить вашу задачу. А шарп, когда я смотрел в последний раз, реверсился очень хорошо и без больших усилий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите. Первая часть: `02 A0 62 FF 00 19`. Большая часть символов нечитаемая, кроме 0x62 = 'b'. Число `0x19 = 25` интересно тем, что читаемые символы начинаются по смещению 24 от начала. Возможно, простое совпадение.

На кириллические символы не похоже, т. к. они должны быть либо с кодами `> 0x80` (для однобайтных кодировок), либо начинаться на одинаковые байты (для UTF-8 и тому подобного).

Идём дальше. `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. Эта часть неинтересна. Нули и минус единицы.

Зато далее идёт `50 65 64 72 6F`. Эти выглядят как ASCII-символы, и дают строку «Pedro». Длины строки (5) в коде не видно, поэтому строка должно быть завершается нулём.

`00 00 00 6A 03`. Интерпретировать не удаётся. Не исключено, что контрольная сумма.

Comment: То есть, не зная как формируется этот набор из 16 ричных чисел, я по сути не смогу его имитировать, правильно?

Comment: @Winteriscoming: Ну по идее да. Если у вас есть название устройства, можно попробовать загуглить его формат общения.